How to Validate Passphrase with Private Key in PHP?
I'm working on validating a passphrase for a private key in PHP. My goal is to confirm whether the provided passphrase is correct for a given private key. Here's the basic approach I’m trying, but I seem to be facing an issue where the validation works even for incorrect passphrases.
What I’ve Tried:
I'm decoding a base64-encoded private key, storing it temporarily in a file, and then using openssl_pkey_get_private() to load the private key with the passphrase. Here's the simplified version of the code:
$private_key_encoded = '...';  // Base64 encoded private key
$passphrase = 'your_passphrase';

// Decode the base64-encoded private key
$private_key_decoded = base64_decode($private_key_encoded);

// Write decoded private key to a temporary file
$tmp_key_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'key');
file_put_contents($tmp_key_file, $private_key_decoded);

// Try to load the private key using the passphrase
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://$tmp_key_file", $passphrase);

if ($privateKey !== false) {
    echo 'Passphrase is correct!';
} else {
    echo 'Passphrase is incorrect!';
}

// Clean up temporary file
unlink($tmp_key_file);

Even when I use the wrong passphrase, openssl_pkey_get_private() returns an OpenSSLAsymmetricKey object (in PHP 8.x). This makes me think the passphrase isn't being strictly validated.
What is the correct way to strictly validate the passphrase for a private key in PHP? Is there a more reliable method to ensure the passphrase is validated? Should I try signing data with the key to force validation?
Any advice or code examples would be appreciated. Thank you!

Can you provide an example private key (not yours), passphrase to test with as well as the incorrect passphrase that passed?

Obviously there is no passphrase in the key file, that's why the call always succeeds.

As a side note, you don't need to use a temporary file, you can pass $private_key_decoded directly to openssl_pkey_get_private().

By the way, why are you using Base64 here? A PEM representation is already ASCII.
